# Using antlr4 go to parse SQL takes too much time

Tags: antlr4

Using antlr4 go to parse SQL takes too much time， eg:

I am using https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/mysql/Positive-Technologies/MySqlParser.g4

```golang
sql := fmt.Sprintf(`select * from xx where id=1`)
    var is *antlr.InputStream
    is = antlr.NewInputStream(sql)
    lexer := parser.NewMySqlLexer(is)
    tokens := antlr.NewCommonTokenStream(lexer, antlr.TokenDefaultChannel)

    p := parser.NewMySqlParser(tokens)

    startTime := time.Now()
    p.Root()
    endTime := time.Now()
    elapsedTime := endTime.Sub(startTime)
    fmt.Printf("Execution time:: %s \n", elapsedTime)
```

output:

Execution time: 50ms

How to optimize it?
Using antlr4 go to parse SQL takes too much time， eg:

I am using https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sql/mysql/Positive-Technologies/MySqlParser.g4

Comment: Too much time compared to what?

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/a7363ce985c3d36320e1d3fc70fe5c46800bc58f/sql/mysql/Positive-Technologies/desc.xml#L4), the Go target is not working because it's slow. As I pointed out [in the PR](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/pull/3545#issuecomment-1600544235), the main issue is that the grammar is very ambiguous (it's a terrible grammar). But it's likely there are some issues with the Go target with grammar ambiguity. You can read the comment that follows about `fullColumnName`.